# Adding seconds to a self.timepicker date (for localnotification purposes)

Tags: ios, loops, localnotification

I want to know if it is possible to add seconds to a local notification? I am trying to create a loop to schedule local notifications 30 seconds after each others. So, in the loop below, can I keep on "delaying" the firedate 30 seconds after each other. I don't know if that question makes sense, but that's the best I can describe my problem as. Think of it as a 30 second interval, but manually scheduling each notification.

```
for (notifs = 1, notifs <= 64, notifs ++)
{
  UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = [self.timePicker date];
```

//can i write it like [self.timePicker date] + 30000?

```
localNotification.soundName = @"notifsound.caf";
localNotification.alertBody = @"Wake Up!!!";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];         
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use NSDate's `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` and just pass the current iteration number multiplied by 30.

```
for (notifs = 1; notifs <= 64; notifs ++)
{
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = [[self.timePicker date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:notifs * 30.0];

    localNotification.soundName = @"notifsound.caf";
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Wake Up!!!";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Comment: @satheeshwaran Glad to hear it! And if my post solved your problem don't forget to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to my post! :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Since I am new to iOS, I am still a tad bit unfamiliar with this stuff. I just want to clarify: Do I need to declare anything else? Or is timePicker the only thing?

Comment: @tantantheman You should be alright with that, and the only other properties I can think to set would be `applicationIconBadgeNumber` and maybe `repeatInterval`.

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't see any notifications now.

Comment: So to be more specific, I have a sound that is 30 seconds long to play in each notification. So I want them to be continuous after each other though. Does that make sense? Maybe there was a misunderstanding somewhere on my part.

Comment: @tantantheman Sorry I left out a line of code that would prevent the notifications from posting! I've updated my post.